# How do I abort HTTP requests fired by Ember Data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model that have to be updated (reloaded) on certain user actions. If two of those actions happen in quick succession, I'd like the first update request to be aborted because a) it's result will be outdated, and b) the request takes some time (so queueing those requests is not an option either).

Is there a way to easily achieve this with Ember Data?

Answer (score 1):

I overrode the application adapter's ajax method to add the XMLHttpRequest object to an array.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  xhr: [],

  ajax: function(url, type, hash) {
    var adapter = this;

    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      hash = adapter.ajaxOptions(url, type, hash);

      hash.success = function(json) {
        Ember.run(null, resolve, json);
      };

      hash.error = function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        Ember.run(null, reject, adapter.ajaxError(jqXHR));
      };

      adapter.xhr.push(Ember.$.ajax(hash));
    }, "DS: RestAdapter#ajax " + type + " to " + url);
  },
});
```

Then, when I want to abort a request (in this case, from a route):

```
this.store.adapterFor('discussion').xhr.forEach(function(xhr) {xhr.abort();});
```